# Most efficient if statement in .zshrc to check whether Linux OS is running on WSL?

Tags: linux, zsh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zshrc

In my .zshrc file I conditionally set my PATH variable depending on whether I'm running on Linux or macOS - I'm now trying to figure out if there's a way I can efficiently detect from my .zshrc if I'm working on Linux running on WSL.

I'm wondering if I can somehow check for the existence of /mnt/c/Program Files or similar - but figure there must be a better way?

Example of my current .zshrc:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH" 
if ! [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
  export PATH="$HOME/.nodenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
fi
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
eval "$(nodenv init -)"
PATH="$HOME/.bin:$PATH"
if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "darwin"* ]]; then
  export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="$HOME/Library/Android/sdk"
  export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/lib/x86_64"
  export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/share/dotnet"
fi
```

If anyone has any better ideas than somehow checking for the existence of /mnt/c/Program Files I'd very much appreciate it!

Comment: `uname -r` contains Microsoft. https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch/blob/master/screenfetch-dev

Comment: Thanks - that was exactly what I needed - popped an answer to my own question in below.

Answer (score 4):

There are many possible way to check WSL in any shell. Most *reliable* ways are:

1. From `uname -r` command output.
2. From `/proc/version` file.
3. From `/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease` file.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if uname -r |grep -q 'Microsoft' ; then
    echo True
fi

if grep -q -i 'Microsoft' /proc/version ; then
    echo True
fi

if grep -q -i 'Microsoft' /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease ; then
    echo True
fi
```

Also there are many file existence can be checked with shell script. For example, only WSL has 1. `/dev/lxss` 2. `/bin/wslpath` 3. `/sbin/mount.drvfs` 4. `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop` 5. `/etc/wsl.conf` files but GNU/Linux distributions has not.

See more:

- [screenFetch](https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch/blob/master/screenfetch-dev)
- [netfetch](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/blob/master/neofetch)

Answer (score 2):

In WSL, there is a special file for checking interoperability called `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop` which is WSL specific file. You can check using the following command:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop ]; then
  echo True
fi
```

or more simple one-line code(in bash):

```
[ -f /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop ]
```

This will return exit code 0 if true, exit code 1 if false.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Biswapiryo's comment - I came up with this solution to detect WSL:

```
if [[ $(uname -r)] == ^*Microsoft$ ]]; then
  # Code goes here
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

*Short/current answer:*

To detect either WSL1 or WSL2, you can use a modified version of [@MichaelSmith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53997721/11810933):

```
#!/bin/zsh

if [[ $(uname -r) == (#s)*[mM]icrosoft*(#e) ]]; then
  echo test
fi
```

*More detail:*

When this question was originally asked, only WSL1 existed, and `uname -r` would return something like:

```
4.4.0-22000-Microsoft
```

This is not a "real" kernel in WSL1, but just the number/name that Microsoft chooses to provide in response to that particular syscall.  The 22000, in this case, is the Windows build number, which currently corresponds to the WSL release.  Note that this is the case even in the current WSL Preview in the Microsoft Store, even though it is decoupled from the Windows release.

With WSL2, however, Microsoft provides a real Linux kernel, which returns something like:

```
5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

Earlier versions may have left off the `-WSL2` portion.

Of course, if you build your own WSL2 kernel, you should update the test to match the kernel name you provide.

Comment: That's sort of true.  It's not really the distro being used as much as the WSL version itself -- The question was originally asked when WSL2 didn't exist, so while it *would* properly detect WSL1 (at that time, and now), it requires slight modification to detect WSL2.  The change is so minor that it probably would have been better as an edit to the existing answer, though.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, I will delete my answer if the answer of Michael has been updated

Comment: On second thought, it's probably worth having a new answer to highlight the reasons *why* a change is needed.  I've edited yours further to make this clear, but feel free to revert if there's something you don't agree with.  Note that you can always edit another user's answer yourself, of course - It just requires that someone else with editing privileges (at 3k rep) approve it first.  But again, let's leave yours in this case to highlight the change.